# problem with creating docker image for spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker

i'm trying to create docker image for spring boot application and i'm getting this error

> Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test (default-test) on project onlineStorePlatform: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test failed: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.apache.maven.surefire:maven-surefire-common:jar:2.18.1, org.apache.maven.surefire:surefire-api:jar:2.18.1, org.apache.maven:maven-core:jar:2.2.1, org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:2.2.1, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interpolation:jar:1.11, org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-parameter-documenter:jar:2.2.1, org.slf4j:slf4j-jdk14:jar:1.5.6, org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.5.6, org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.5.6, org.apache.maven.reporting:maven-reporting-api:jar:3.0, org.apache.maven:maven-profile:jar:2.2.1, org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:2.2.1, org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:2.2.1, org.apache.maven:maven-error-diagnostics:jar:2.2.1, org.apache.maven:maven-project:jar:2.2.1, org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-registry:jar:2.2.1, org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-descriptor:jar:2.2.1, org.apache.maven:maven-artifact-manager:jar:2.2.1, backport-util-concurrent:backport-util-concurrent:jar:3.1, org.apache.maven:maven-monitor:jar:2.2.1, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:1.5.15, org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:2.2.1, org.apache.maven.plugin-tools:maven-plugin-annotations:jar:3.3: Cannot access central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) in offline mode and the artifact org.apache.maven.surefire:maven-surefire-common:jar:2.18.1 has not been downloaded from it before. -> [Help 1]

POM.xml file

```
<project 
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>io.javabrains.spring</groupId>
  <artifactId>onlineStorePlatform</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>onlineStorePlatform</name>


    <!-- step #1: add the parent -->
  <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
  </parent>
  <!-- End of step #1 -->


  <!-- step #2: create dependencies -->

  <dependencies>

         <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.19</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.0.jre8</version>
        </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <!-- step #3: change java version -->
 <properties>
         <java.versions>13.0.1</java.versions>
 </properties>

 <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <finalName>onlineStoreplatform</finalName>
 </build>

 </project>
```

and finally the content of Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:8
EXPOSE 8080
ADD target/onlineStoreplatform.jar onlineStoreplatform.jar 
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/onlineStoreplatform.jar"]
```

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Omar, what does onlineStoreplatform.jar include? Just the codes of your project, or the whole project and it's dependencies? Try to find out how to package the project and the dependencies with together. You do not need to pull the dependencies.  I guess this will help https://howtodoinjava.com/maven/create-fat-jar-spring-boot-applications/

Answer (score 1):

Did you read the stacktrace?

`Cannot access central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) in offline mode and the artifact org.apache.maven.surefire:maven-surefire-common:jar:2.18.1 has not been downloaded from it before`

It looks like your build engine is not connected to the internet.

Comment: can you specify which build engine do you mean?
docker or what?

Comment: well for me it looks like it's maven. Can you execute script `mvn clean -U`? `-U` means update dependencies. If that works then anything else should work also. If not, try to resolve you network issue.

Comment: but i updated the whole project and i'm still getting the same error message

Comment: how did you updated the whole project. What kind of commands are you running? What was the output of `mvn clean -U`? Please learn how to provide more details otherwise nobody will help you ;)

Comment: no i didn't update the project using any commands but i've made this by:
right click on the project => maven => update project

Comment: well and are you sure it was updated? :) try with maven to see what happens.

Comment: i've executed the command successfully , but nothing change ,  i'm still getting the same error .
what i'm supposed to do now?

Comment: what does mean nothing change? your answers/questions are really bad. Try to put more context to that.